# Can Mercurial print command success messages instead of no response?

Tags: mercurial

Can Mercurial print command success messages instead of no response in the output prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could write`post-<command>`[hooks](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks) to output whatever you want on succesful commands. I don't see what the benefit would be however.

the [book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/) has a tutorial on hooks doing [almost exactly what you want but with commit](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#sec:hook:simple)
. note with a post-command hook you shouldn't need to check the result for success as the hook will only be run if the command was successful.

Comment: This definitely seems like the correct answer, however I know 0 python any chance I could get some help on what I'd want this to look like? `if $HG_RESULT == 0 echo Reverted successfully`

Comment: you dont need to use python. the book has a good guide on how to set up hook via the shell.

Answer (score 3):

It [returns a value](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ExitCodes), hence you can wrap it around a script.

Comment: That's not exactly the answer to my question, I specifically want to know if it can actually print a success message, but this is useful to know.